# Match white space above chapter title to top margin as defined in geometry package

Tags: chapters, titlesec, geometry

I would like to change the position of chapter titles, specifically the amount of white space above them. I am using the `book` class and defining margins using the `geometry` package. The chapter command prints the chapter title below the text boundaries of non-chapter-starting pages, which in my opinion looks ugly. How can this be changed?

PS: I should also mention that I am using the `titlesec` package to customize my titles. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\thechapter}\hspace{0.8ex}\textcolor{lightgray}{\fontsize{35}{0}\selectfont |}\hspace{0.8ex}}{0ex}{\Huge\bfseries}

\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}
\chapter{The Theory of Solid State Physics}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please load package `showframe`. Do i understand you correctly that you want the top of your chapter title touching that line fencing the type area?

Comment: @Johannes_B That's correct.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for titlespacing. I copied the original from `titlesec.sty` and just set the former value of 50 pt (rather `50\p@`) to zero points. There still is a little skip, but i think it's ok the way it is. You can of course set a negative value instead if you want to.

I also changed the width of the marginal column to 22 mm. I am not sure if you are using marginal notes of any kind, but seeing that little showframe-rectangle going out of the paper makes me furious ;-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage[margin=30mm
,marginparwidth=22mm% Seems reasonable
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}



%Here it the important part
\makeatletter
%copied from titlesec.sty
\titlespacing*\chapter
{\z@}%
{\z@}%<-- formerly 50pt
{\ttl@chapafter}%
\makeatother



\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\thechapter}\hspace{0.8ex}\textcolor{lightgray}{\fontsize{35}{0}\selectfont
|}\hspace{0.8ex}}{0ex}{\Huge\bfseries}

\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}
\chapter{The Theory of Solid State Physics}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had hoped it was possible to somehow lock the chapter to the text boundary without having to adjust a vertical height by trial and error. This does look a lot better though.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[total={6.5in,10.75in},top=-1in, left=0.9in, includefoot]{geometry}   
\usepackage{lipsum}   
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\thechapter}\hspace{0.8ex}\textcolor{lightgray}{\fontsize{35}{0}\selectfont |}\hspace{0.8ex}}
{0ex}{\Huge\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\chapter{The Theory of Solid State Physics}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The top margin option can be defined just to reduce space between chapter heading and top. Top can be set as you like starting from -0.1in to 1in.

output

[image: topmargin]

Comment: Please use the [proper markup](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for your code, so it is displayed nicely and copy/pastes correctly. Surely you've been here long enough to notice this. Additionally, this code sets a near-zero top margin, which will not print correctly on _many_ printers.

Comment: There is a `\par` in your titleformat. I guess it is a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: It might be me, but I'm not sure I understand how this does what I want. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Page dimension of geometry package is defined width, height. Here we are concerned with total body height = textheight = headheight+headsep+footskip). Top margin is separate which is 1 in default. So you can reduce top margin by defining top with negative sign. So head moves upwards when you define top

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the output generated by Johannes_B's suggestion a little more desirable but I appreciate the help.